# sed remove json suboject from a json string

Tags: json, sed

I try to preprocess a JSON file and want to remove all subobjects in it.

Note that my JSON string is inline (not have \r).

In input I have:

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "result": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "createdOn" : 123456,
      "obj1": {
         ...:...,
         ...:...
      },
      "obj2": {
         ...:...,
         ...:...
      },
      "otherattribute": "..."
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "createdOn" : 123456,
      "obj1": {
         ...:...,
         ...:...
      },
      "obj2": {
         ...:...,
         ...:...
      },
      "otherattribute": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

And want to have:

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "result": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "createdOn" : 123456,
      "otherattribute": "..."
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "createdOn" : 123456,
      "otherattribute": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried to use sed command with :

```
sed 's/"obj1":{[^}]*//g'
```

It will remove the "ojb1" subobject, but let remain the endind "}," of this subobject.
I didn't find the way to also remove "},".

How?

Second question: I know the list of suboject; but is there a way to remove all theses subjects directly without knowing there name? Something like:

```
sed 's/".*":{[^}]*//g'
```

So that I will have only one sed command and not having to chain commands like :

```
sed 's/obj1//g' | sed 's/obj2//g' | sed 's/obj3//g' ...
```

Comment: I wouldn’t even _think_ about editing JSON with sed. Whatever you write with sed, I’ll create a unit test in two minutes that breaks it.

Comment: Super... The json string I have to parse will be always formatted with the same.. format. It's not a completely generic JSON string. So I guess I can use a sed to preprocess my json string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving a first answer:

```
sed 's/"obj1":{[^}},]*//g'
```

It will match `"obj1":` until character `}` and then match again `},`, so that these last 2 chars will be also deleted (replaced with nothing).

Now I try to do something more generic to match any object name, with something like this:

```
sed 's/"[[:alnum:]]":{[^}},]*//g'
```

But it's not working...
I've already tried to escape or escape escape or escape escape escape double quote without success...